# How to use R for multi-response questions in a survey and make comparison?

Tags: r, spss

I've not found anything that is quite helpful for converting "MRSETS" command in SPSS into R. I am looking for similar codes for grouping multi-response questions for further analysis and making comparison between questions in survey and finding trend across some regions.

how do i get such output in R. Thanks